# Can't get binary code to replicate in loop

Tags: python, loops, binary

First off I'm generally new to coding, and this is one of my first posts asking for help, so sorry if i leave anything out.
I'm writing a code in python to get the following output:

```
Please enter number: 10

Decimal: 1 = binary: 1
Decimal: 2 = binary: 10
Decimal: 3 = binary: 11
Decimal: 4 = binary: 100
Decimal: 5 = binary: 101
Decimal: 6 = binary: 110
Decimal: 7 = binary: 111
Decimal: 8 = binary: 1000
Decimal: 9 = binary: 1001
Decimal: 10 = binary: 1010
```

I have been stuck for quite a while and thought my best option would be to ask here.

```
 rqn3=int(input("Please enter a number: "))
 while decimal < rqn3:
   for decimal in range(1, rqn3+1):
        remainder = rqn3 % 2
        rqn3 = rqn3 // 2
        answer = str(remainder) + answer
        decimal+1
        print("Decimal:",decimal ,"= binary:",answer)
   decimal+1
```

Resulting in:

```
Please enter a number: 2
Decimal: 1 = binary: 0
Decimal: 2 = binary: 10
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code does not produce the result you claim.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  This problem is solved in many places on line.  If you need *your* code fixed, then you need to give us a problem specification and analysis.  The code you posted shows multiple problems, rather than a single error to fix.  You seem to be trying to run nested `for` loops, but you need to learn how to increment a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt method to convert into binary. You can find details about bin method from https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin

```
rqn3=int(input("Please enter a number: "))
for i in range(1,rqn3+1):
    print("Decimal:",i ,"= binary:",bin(i)[2:])
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a number of options.

Probably the easiest way is to just do this:

```py
rqn3 = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

for i in range(1, rqn3 + 1):
    print(f'Decimal: {i} = binary: {i:b}')
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number: 10
Decimal: 1 = binary: 1
Decimal: 2 = binary: 10
Decimal: 3 = binary: 11
Decimal: 4 = binary: 100
Decimal: 5 = binary: 101
Decimal: 6 = binary: 110
Decimal: 7 = binary: 111
Decimal: 8 = binary: 1000
Decimal: 9 = binary: 1001
Decimal: 10 = binary: 1010
```

Assuming you wanted to do the computation yourself, you can use [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```py
rqn3 = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

for i in range(1, rqn3 + 1):
    num = i
    result = ""
    while num != 0:
        num, r = divmod(num, 2)
        result = str(r) + result
    print(f'Decimal: {i} = binary: {result}')
```

(Output same as above)

---

Your issue was that you have your loops out of order. The `while` loop produces the binary for *a* number, so it should be your inner loop. Your `for` loop is *providing* the values to process.